# How to get variable from for loop

Tags: python

I want to iterate over a list, and then pass that variable to another Python file, witch writes that text.

forloop.py:

```
 class Main:
    def list():
        list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
        for i in list:
            print_this_variable = i
```

That iterates over the list, now i want to print the results in a separate file.

print.py:

```
from forloop import *
print(print_this_variable)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Simply calling Main.list() will print the results in your separate file.

Comment: I suggest you learn about so-called variable scope. In this case, `print_this_variable` is a local variable. This is because it is declared inside a function and has nothing to do with the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the way you've configured things. The variable `print_this_variable` is local to `list` and won't be available outside of that method.

Here's one way to structure things (there are a variety of other ways, but your question isn't very clear about what you're actually trying to accomplish):

First, note that `list` is the name of the Python `list` data type -- you shouldn't use it as a name for functions or variables. Second, you shouldn't name variables the same as functions, because this will mask the function name and will probably bite you at some point.

So, in `forloop.py`, let's do this:

```
class Main:
   def example_function(self):
     data = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
     for i in data:
       self.print_this_variable = i
```

That makes `print_this_variable` an instance variable for `Main` objects.

In `print.py`, we could write:

```
import forloop

# We need to create a Main object
m = forloop.Main()

# The `print_this_variable` attribute isn't available until
# after we # call the `example_function` method.
m.example_function()

# Now we can ask for the instance attribute
print(m.print_this_variable)
```